# Bootstrap Column Not Showing on Mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, bootstrap-4

So I'm trying to have a two column layout, one for text, and another for just an image. Everything looks good on desktop, but when viewing on mobile, the image column doesn't show up. How do I get it so that when viewing the page on mobile devices that the image column is the first section after the navbar covering full width, not split vertically, then the text column?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <!--Text Column-->
            <div class="col-sm-6 sec-1">
                <h1>Frank Kreutzer</h1>
                <h2>Frontend Web Developer</h2>
                <p>Leverage agile frameworks to provide a robust synopsis for high level overviews. Iterative approaches to corporate strategy foster collaborative thinking to further the overall value proposition. Organically grow the holistic world view of disruptive innovation via workplace diversity and empowerment.</p>
            </div>
            <!--Image Column-->
            <div class="col-sm-6 sec-2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's a codepen of the page: https://codepen.io/Frankk97/pen/QBBNym/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a column layout on all devices, then you should use class `col-6` and not `col-sm-6`.

As specified in [bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options) documentation, selector for screensize <576px is `.col-`. `.col-sm` which you have used is for screensize >=576px.

Here is the modified [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WKKwoJ?editors=1000).

**Edit**

Updated the codepen to show image to cover full width and as first section on mobile. Updated the parent div to use bootstrap flex -

```
<div class="row d-flex flex-column-reverse flex-sm-row">
```

and then updated child divs to cover full screen on mobile.

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 sec-1">
```

Added a new class and media query css for the image div.

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 sec-2 image-section"></div>

@media screen and (max-width: 575px) {
    .image-section {
        height: 200px;
    }
}
```

Comment: That fixed it! Do you by chance know of how I could get the image to be the first section when viewed on mobile, like this: https://imgur.com/a/vqDmqlv?

Comment: Do you need image to cover full width on mobile or keep the column layout but display image on left?

Comment: Cover full width probably should have specified that.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

To get the image to show, set a height on the respective div. For the reverse arrangement set a media query that has a flex-direction of column-reverse.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following style

```
@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .sec-2 {
    height: 300px;
  }
}
```

It is needed because you have added that image as background-image. Since the div has no content and wraps in resolutions below 576px, it doesn't take up height. HEnce you need to add some height specifically to that element in small screens.

Also use order classes to change order on devices. See the use of it below.

Also i removed the `sec1` class, as it was not necessary.

```css
.navbar {
  /*background: #031426;*/
}

.navbar li a {
  color: #000;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s, all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.navbar li a:hover {
  color: #E64BA7;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: left;
}

.container-fluid {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.sec-1 {
  height: 100vh;
}

.sec-1 h2 {
  color: #E64BA7;
}

.sec-2 {
  background-image: url("https://frankkreutzer.com/assets/images/pink.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .sec-2 {
    height: 300px;
  }
}

footer {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
}

footer p {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #E64BA7;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer ul {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

footer li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px;
}

footer li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*border-bottom: medium none;*/
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s, all 1s ease 0s;
}

.icon {
  background-color: #222;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  height: 5em;
  width: 5em;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
}

.icon a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.facebook {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-size: 25%;
}

.facebook:hover {
  background-color: #3664A2;
}

.linkedin {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-size: 50%;
}

.linkedin:hover {
  background-color: #007BB6;
}

.github {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-size: 60%;
}

.github:hover {
  background-color: #6CC644;
}

.codepen {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-size: 70%;
}

.codepen:hover {
  background-color: #76DAFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Frank Kreutzer</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/images/logo.png" width="32" height="32">
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.12/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-G0fIWCsCzJIMAVNQPfjH08cyYaUtMwjJwqiRKxxE/rx96Uroj1BtIQ6MLJuheaO9" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!--Custom CSS-->
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Google Fonts-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <!--Start Header-->
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="assets/images/logo.png" width="64px" height="64px">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto float-right">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Portfolio</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Blog</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
          </li>

        </ul>
      </div>

    </nav>
  </header>
  <!--End Header-->

  <main role="main">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 order-2 order-sm-1">
          <h1>Frank Kreutzer</h1>
          <p>Leverage agile frameworks to provide a robust synopsis for high level overviews. Iterative approaches to corporate strategy foster collaborative thinking to further the overall value proposition. Organically grow the holistic world view of disruptive
            innovation via workplace diversity and empowerment.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm sec-2 order-1 order-sm-2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container content">

      <h1>Test</h1>
      <p>Leverage agile frameworks to provide a robust synopsis for high level overviews. Iterative approaches to corporate strategy foster collaborative thinking to further the overall value proposition. Organically grow the holistic world view of disruptive
        innovation via workplace diversity and empowerment.</p>

      <p>Bring to the table win-win survival strategies to ensure proactive domination. At the end of the day, going forward, a new normal that has evolved from generation X is on the runway heading towards a streamlined cloud solution. User generated content
        in real-time will have multiple touchpoints for offshoring.</p>

      <p>Capitalize on low hanging fruit to identify a ballpark value added activity to beta test. Override the digital divide with additional clickthroughs from DevOps. Nanotechnology immersion along the information highway will close the loop on focusing
        solely on the bottom line.</p>

    </div>

  </main>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="page-footer text-center">
    <p>&#169; Frank Kreuzter 2018</p>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="facebook icon">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/frank.kreutzer.97" target="_blank"></a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="linkedin icon">
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/frank-kreutzer-205443121?authType=NAME_SEARCH&authToken=i1OO&locale=en_US&trk=tyah&trkInfo=clickedVertical%3Amynetwork%2CclickedEntityId%3A505715045%2CauthType%3ANAME_SEARCH%2Cidx%3A1-1-1%2CtarId%3A1487182355694%2Ctas%3AFrank"
            target="_blank"></a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="github icon">
          <a href="https://github.com/frankkreutzer" target="_blank"></a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="codepen icon">
          <a href="http://codepen.io/Frankk97/" target="_blank"></a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <li><a href="#about">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </footer>

  <!--Custom JS-->
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>

  <!--Bootstrap Core JS-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For mobile device:
Three equal columns:
Get three equal-width columns **starting at desktops and scaling to large desktops. On mobile devices**, tablets and below, the columns will automatically stack.

```css
h4 {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.row {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.row .row {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
      margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
[class*="col-"] {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-color: rgba(86,61,124,.15);
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border: 1px solid rgba(86,61,124,.2);
}

hr {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
      </div>
```